# Green numeral in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2014

[image: Green numeral]

Why do I get a numeral green in Illustrator when I write it as text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hidden characters may be on. Go to:

Type > Show Hidden Characters

Comment: And they are green because they use their layer's color. It's all in the manual.